# How do you specify unique=True for WTForms-Alchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I have the following class:

```
class Cloaker(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  domain = db.Column(db.String(32), unique=True, nullable=False, info={
    'description': 'Raw Domain Only (no www). i.e. hello.com',
    'validators': raw_domain_validator,
  })
```

*(Note the **unique=True** for domain)*

With a form generated by WTForm:

```
class CloakerForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Cloaker
```

I have the following code which handles CRUD for this model:

```
@cloaker_bp.route('/new/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cloaker_bp.route('/<cloaker_id>/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cloaker(cloaker_id=None):
  cloaker = Cloaker.query.get(cloaker_id) if cloaker_id else Cloaker()
  if request.method == 'GET':
    form = CloakerForm(obj=cloaker)
    form.populate_obj(cloaker)
  else:
    form = CloakerForm(request.form)
    if form.validate():
      form.populate_obj(cloaker)
      db.session.add(cloaker)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('.list_cloakers'))

  return render_template('cloaker/single.html', form=form, cloaker=cloaker)
```

When I update an object, I am consistently getting `Already exists.` for domain.

When I follow **Using unique validator with existing objects** on wtforms-alchemy's website:

```
  ...(from the CRUD view)... 
  else:
    form = CloakerForm(obj=cloaker)
    #form = CloakerForm(request.form)
    form.populate_obj(cloaker)
    if form.validate():
      db.session.add(cloaker)
      db.session.commit()
```

I am getting `This field is required.` for domain. I don't understand how WTForms-Alchemy is getting their data from request.form if I follow their recommendations.

## How can I get unique=True to work with my views?

Answer (score 0):

Was having the "already exists" problem on POST/UPDATE as well.  But the [doc's solution](http://wtforms-alchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html#using-unique-validator-with-existing-objects) did help in my case:

`obj = MyModel.query.get(1)
    form = MyForm(obj=obj)
    form.populate_obj(obj)
    form.validate()`

Thanks, because this question helped me find the section in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

With WTForms-Alchemy version 0.17.0 I've found that if I do

```
 record = MyModel.query.filter(MyModel.id = <some valid number>).one()
```

And then when `request.method == 'POST'`

```
 my_form = MyModelForm(request.form, obj=record)
```

Providing both the `request.form` and `obj` param addresses the Unique validator and gets around the required field BUT still allows updates.